# Como exibir uma mensagem de confirmação ao clicar na opção excluir do grid?

Tags: vb.net

Estou tentando fazer com essa função, mas não to conseguindo!

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(objLivros.GetType(), "confirm", "confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse item?')", True)
```

Comment: ja tentou usar alert() ?

Comment: usei sim, mas só apareceu a mensagem "OK"

Comment: Respondi abaixo, tente fazer desta forma.

Comment: Você colocar o ScriptManager na sua página?

Comment: Veja se [esse link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/552014/howpluscanplusiplusgetplustheplusreturnplusvaluepl) te ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox.Show()` é o que você estava precisando:

### *Jeito avançado*, com handles para se o usuário clicar em Sim, não ou cancelar.

```
  REM esse Label é onde vamos usar o nosso GoTo se ele ignorar a mensagem.
start:

  REM você pode adicionar mais argumentos...
  Dim Resultado As Int32 = MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente excluir esse item?", "Título", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Info)

  'MessageBoxButtons -> Botões em que vão aparecer na janela
  'MessageBoxIcon    -> O ícone que vai aparecer do lado da janela

  Select Case Resultado
      Case DialogResult.OK 'Ou DialogResult.Yes
          REM aqui fica o código quando o usuário clicar no 'Sim'.
      Case DialogResult.Cancel Or DialogResult.No
          REM e aqui o código se ele clicou em não, ou cancelar.
      Case Is Nothing
          REM aqui se ele não pressionou nenhum botão, se ele ignorou a janela...
          GoTo start ' Aqui vai retornar para o label start...
      Case Else
          REM outro botão que ele aperto...
  End Select
```

### *Jeito simplificado*, apenas sim ou não.

```
     Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente excluir esse item?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
     Select Case result
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
           REM decidiu colocar sim...
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
           REM decidiu colocar não...
     End Select
```

Comment: Acho que ele estava perguntando como fazer o Handler na hora que a grid é clicada.

Comment: Só colocar esse código no evento `Control.MouseClick`, já que é um (se for um) controle WindowsForms, é suportado

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `alert()`

segue modelo que encontrei no [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert2):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello\nHow are you?");
}
```

Comment: alert não funciona...
Eu quero fazer isso na hora de excluir do grid, lá no RowCommand, se for sim então cai na minha função de exclusão, se for não ele sai da sub!

Answer (score 0):

Porque não usa o msgbox? Ficaria algo assim:

```
Dim decisao As Integer = MsgBox("Deseja realmente excluir esse item?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)

    If decisao = 1 Then

        'Código de exclusão aqui
    Else

        'Aqui nada acontece...
End If
```

Você pode por esse simples trecho em qualquer lugar, por exemplo no evento clique para excluir do seu grid...

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente:

```
If MsgBox("Tem certeza que deseja sair?", vbYesNo, "Confirmação") = vbYes Then
            If vbYes Then
                Me.Close()
            End If
            If vbNo Then
            Else
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do da classe, inclua este método, e veja se dará o resultado que você espera:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsPostBack)
            {
                string eventTarget = (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
                string eventArgument = (this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

                if (eventTarget == "ConfirmacaoCliente")
                {
                    if (eventArgument == "true")
                    {
                        //Faça algo caso o cliente clique em 'Ok'
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Faça algo caso o cliente clique em 'Cancel'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myScript = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
                                    var confirmation = window.confirm('Deseja excluir este item?');
                                    __doPostBack('ConfirmacaoCliente', confirmation);
                                </script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", myScript);
        }
```

[Fonte do código](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/6d09f731-b34e-4f17-baca-200f5a997dcd/urgente-scriptmanagerregisterstartupscript?forum=aspnetpt)